# How to create a true 'Random' with Timer control?

Tags: c#, random, timer

I have a timer that clicks a button, and no matter what speed the timer is at, due to the `Random` having some kind of association with the clock, the outcome is predictable no matter what the speed.

I have been reading up and learned that when a new `Random` is initialized, it is done so with the system time, which explains why I'm getting this problem.

Here's what I have:

```
   int win = 0;
   int lose = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int rnu = rn.Next(2);

        if (rnu == 0)
            win++;

        if (rnu == 1)
            lose++;

          string winmsg = "Wins: " + win.ToString();
          string losemsg = "Losses: " + lose.ToString();

        winlbl.Text = winmsg;
        loselbl.Text = losemsg;

        timer1.Start();

    }
```

And then the timer:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.PerformClick(); //interval 500, but always predictable.
    }
```

My goal is to try to create a more 'Random' outcome- one that wouldn't be predictable with the timer control. However, I can't modify the speed of the timer; it must remain constant for the cycle.

I've tried stopping the timer and restarting, but even then it carries on the predictable behavior.

Does anyone know of a way to get around this or some kind of 'trick'? Or is this some C# `Random` limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been reading up and learned that when a new Random is initialized, it is done so with the system time, which explains why I'm getting this problem.

Then move the `Random` outside the method and don't reinitialize it.

```
Random rn = new Random(); 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

The point of the `Random` class is that you shouldn't have too many instances around your program, exactly because they could be initialized at the same time. The perfect number would be exactly one for each thread (in which you use it). Winforms events all run in the main thread.

Comment: I should have known better >_< Thanks for showing me and for the explanation.